# Publishing Website on Visual Studio 2010 fails (MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, publish

I am trying to publish the website using Publish option provided in the properties of the solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2010 but I am getting errors , below is the error:

Error 1 Copying file obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Content\css\Site.css to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Content\css\Site.css failed. Could not find file 'obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Content\css\Site.css'

Any ideas or suggestion , why this error is popping up causing publishing to fail. Also I check my obj\Release folder , almost all the files have got an exclaimation mark next to it.

Comment: Why would a file have an exclamation next to it?  Are you using some sort of versioning like SVN?  If you are then have you checked for conflicts etc?

Comment: No I am not using anything , I just deleted the Site.css and republish it not its giving errors on all the scripts which have exclamation mark on it , i have no idea why there are exclamation marks it works fine locally all the scripts are there.

Answer (score 14):

Go into windows explorer, navigate to the root of your website, locate the `bin` and `obj` folders and send them to the recycle bin. Build the app and try to publish again.

**EDIT**

It's because you have a file reference in your project that doesn't exist or is a different version to what your project file expects. Try clicking the `Show All Files` in the solution explorer and finding the file with the yellow triangle next to it. Then right click -> Exclude from project. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Did you build your application before publishing?

Comment: it comes up with this error Error 1 Copying file obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Tools.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Tools.dll failed. Could not find file 'obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Tools.dll'.  0 0 ApexTrackDays

Comment: The file is already there in the 'obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Tools.dll' folder , i dont why it cant find it

Answer (score 0):

I guess you delete some project file directly(not from project)
Project still have reference to them and looking for them while publishing

Close Solution and Open it Again then delete file from Project

Answer (score 0):

Realise this has been answered but thought I would contribute.

Received the same error.  The file was showing as there in Visual Studio.

Eventually I tried to open it and couldn't.

Turns out one of the other devs had excluded the file and then committed to source control (TFS).  I then got the latest.

My subsequent publish failed, although build succeeded (it was a cshtml file so this was to be expected).

I excluded the file from my project also and all worked.

Hope this helps someone else out, I'm ashamed to say I lost an hour of my life to this...

Answer (score -1):

It is looking for file that does not exists,
if your wile is missing in solution it will not allow to build.

this is problem in solution thinking that file is exists and if you look via windows explorer to location where the file is supossed to be, it is not there anymore. So it is trying to copy nonexisting file ..

Hope this helps

--misread

right button on the file.
select option build action and select content
copy to output directory select copy always (this will ensure coping the file into the directory)

publish and the file should be there

and you should be ready to go:)

Comment: I mentioned above the file is already there , but when i publish the file dissapears